# How to simply transpose two columns into a single row in postgres?

Tags: postgresql

Following is the output of my query:

```
key                                ;value
"2BxtRdkRvwc-2hPjF8LBmHD-finapril" ;4
"3QXORSfsIY0-2sDizCyvY6m-finapril" ;12
"4QXORSfsIY0-2sDizCyvY6m-curr"     ;12
"5QXORSfsIY0-29Xcom4SHVh-finapril" ;12
```

What i want is simply to bring the rows into columns so that only one row remains with the key as the column name.

I have seen examples with crosstab catering to much complex use cases but i want to know if there is a simpler way in which this can be achieved in my particular case?

Any help is appreciated
Thanks

Postgres Version : 9.5.10

Comment: Can you show an example of the output/result you want?

Answer (score 1):

It is impossible to execute a query resulting in an unknown number and names of columns. The simplest way to get a similar effect is to generate a json object which can be easily interpreted by a client app as a *pivot table*, example:

```
with the_data(key, value) as (
    values
    ('2BxtRdkRvwc-2hPjF8LBmHD-finapril', 4),
    ('3QXORSfsIY0-2sDizCyvY6m-finapril', 12),
    ('4QXORSfsIY0-2sDizCyvY6m-curr', 12),
    ('5QXORSfsIY0-29Xcom4SHVh-finapril', 12)
)

select jsonb_object_agg(key, value)
from the_data;
```

The query returns this json object:

```
{
    "4QXORSfsIY0-2sDizCyvY6m-curr": 12,
    "2BxtRdkRvwc-2hPjF8LBmHD-finapril": 4,
    "3QXORSfsIY0-2sDizCyvY6m-finapril": 12,
    "5QXORSfsIY0-29Xcom4SHVh-finapril": 12
}
```